# How to add space between cards in same row in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a `n x 3` matrix sort of layout. In which each element is a card. I am trying to implement it using vuetify. But, the problem is the cards are getting displayed, but there is no space between them. Even if i add a new row in it. There is no distance between that too.

I have tried using different classes and normal HTML & CSS. But it is not making it responsive

This is how the code loooks like

```
<template lang="html">
<v-container>
<v-layout>
    <v-flex xs12 md4>
      <v-card>
        <v-img
          class="white--text"
          height="200px"
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
        >
          <!-- <v-container> -->
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 align-end flexbox>
                <span class="headline">Top 10 Australian beaches</span>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          <!-- </v-container> -->
        </v-img>
        <v-card-title>
          <div>
            <span class="grey--text">Number 10</span><br>
            <span>Whitehaven Beach</span><br>
            <span>Whitsunday Island, Whitsunday Islands</span>
          </div>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn flat color="orange">Share</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat color="orange">Explore</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>


    <v-flex xs12 md4>
      <v-card>
        <v-img
          class="white--text"
          height="200px"
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
        >
          <v-container>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 align-end flexbox>
                <span class="headline">Top 10 Australian beaches</span>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-container>
        </v-img>
        <v-card-title>
          <div>
            <span class="grey--text">Number 10</span><br>
            <span>Whitehaven Beach</span><br>
            <span>Whitsunday Island, Whitsunday Islands</span>
          </div>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn flat color="orange">Share</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat color="orange">Explore</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>


    <v-flex xs12 md4 >
      <v-card>
        <v-img
          class="white--text"
          height="200px"
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
        >
          <v-container>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 align-end flexbox>
                <span class="headline">Top 10 Australian beaches</span>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-container>
        </v-img>
        <v-card-title>
          <div>
            <span class="grey--text">Number 10</span><br>
            <span>Whitehaven Beach</span><br>
            <span>Whitsunday Island, Whitsunday Islands</span>
          </div>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn flat color="orange">Share</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat color="orange">Explore</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>

//New Row


  <v-layout>


    <v-flex xs12 md4 >
      <v-card>
        <v-img
          class="white--text"
          height="200px"
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
        >
          <v-container>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 align-end flexbox>
                <span class="headline">Top 10 Australian beaches</span>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-container>
        </v-img>
        <v-card-title>
          <div>
            <span class="grey--text">Number 10</span><br>
            <span>Whitehaven Beach</span><br>
            <span>Whitsunday Island, Whitsunday Islands</span>
          </div>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn flat color="orange">Share</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat color="orange">Explore</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>

  </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

This is how the page looks like right now.

[image]

how do I add space between the cards and make it responsive as well.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried your scenario. you have to add this line.

```
<v-container grid-list-md>
```

instead of

```
<v-container>
```

[image]

Here is running example. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EBNPQb?&editable=true&editors=101

Comment: any idea, on how do i increase the space?

Comment: you can change `grid-list-md` to `grid-list-lg` or `grid-list-xl` to have more space.

Comment: @abhigyannayak how about `gap` attribute?